# How to export more than 10,000 stock items records with Web Services

Tags: acumatica

I am able to export even 1000 records, but when the number of records is too big the server returns an error.

The Web Services Schema says I can `limit` the export with the `topCount` parameter.

But it does not allow to `offset` or `paginate` the results.

Is there a way to get the results paginated, or maybe create an export job and then query until the job gets completed and download the data?

What is the proper way to export a big amount of data on Acumatica using Web Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use filters in web services to restrict amount of data.
This would be the best way.